# Internal Server Error 500 when submitting PHP form to email

Tags: php, html, forms, internal-server-error

I am trying to send the content in this form to an email. However, it isn't working and when I submit it gives me an internal error. Here is the code that runs when I am submitting the form.

```
<?php
if(!isset($_POST['submit']))
{
//This page should not be accessed directly. Need to submit the form.
echo "error; you need to submit the form!";
}


$name = $_POST['first_name']; // required

$job = $_POST['job']; // required

$company = $_POST['company']; // required

$email = $_POST['email']; // required

$telephone = $_POST['telephone']; // required

$psn = $_POST['psn']; // required

$un = $_POST['un']; // required

$weight = $_POST['weight']; // not required

$pieces = $_POST['pieces']; // required

$dgpacked = $_POST['dgpacked']; // required

$address = $_POST['address']; // required

$readytime = $_POST['readytime']; // required

$deliverytype = $_POST['deliverytype']; // required


if(IsInjected($email))
{
echo "Bad email value!";
exit;
}

$email_from = 'c.oswald@live.com';//<== update the email address
$email_subject = "New Quote Request submission";
$email_body = "You have received a new message from the $name with $company.\n".
"Here is the message:\n $message".

$to = "c.oswald@live.com";//<== update the email address
$headers = "From: $email_from \r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: $email \r\n";

//Send the email!
mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
//done. redirect to thank-you page.
header('Location: home.html');


// Function to validate against any email injection attempts
function IsInjected($str)
{
  $injections = array('(\n+)',
          '(\r+)',
          '(\t+)',
          '(%0A+)',
          '(%0D+)',
          '(%08+)',
          '(%09+)'
          );
  $inject = join('|', $injections);
  $inject = "/$inject/i";
  if(preg_match($inject,$str))
    {
return true;
  }
  else
{
return false;
  }
}

?>
```

If there is anything more simple, please help me out, I just need something simple enough to understand but not so basic I will have security or injection problems.

Comment: Check the PHP error log.

Comment: @Mike don't mean to sound silly but where can I find that? since I can't see anything when I submit the form but the internal server error.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5127838/where-does-php-store-the-error-log

Comment: Depends on your server but if you are on a Linux machine it would be something like /var/log/error.log

Comment: @JayBlanchard nope i'm on a mac and i'm super stuck!

Comment: If you're using MAMP the log should be /Applications/MAMP/logs/php_error.log

Answer (score 0):

For email verification, you can easily use [FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL](http://www.w3schools.com/php/filter_validate_email.asp). I think that is better than using your own function.

I have not found any other mistake in your code, so I think that it is your function. Otherwise it could lead to a server misconfiguration, then I need the error log entry for investigation. If you use MAMP on your Mac, you can find the error log at /Applications/MAMP/logs/php_error.log.

For mailing purposes, I can recommend [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) to you.

(In the first statement

```
if(!isset($_POST['submit']))
```

an *exit;* is missing. After the header-redirect, also an *exit;* should take place. Furthermore, you should check that all necessary parameters are passed by the client.)

Answer (score 0):

This will happen due to the following reasons:

Unhanded error in Code, Syntax errors and Explicit Codes.

For Sending email the best php class is : https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer

It is the latest PHPMailer Class.

After downloading this file, you can see mail.php file. There you have to change the username, password, recipients and message etc.